# Jetty and GWT (Google Web Toolkit)

Tags: gwt, jetty

As I understand it, GWT uses an embedded Jetty server. Can 
anyone please tell me where I can find the Jetty .xml configuration files 
used by GWT? I have a webapp which makes uses of Jetty's 
ContinuationFilter and ProxyServlet. The app works fine under GWT but 
fails when run in a separate Jetty instance outside of GWT. If I can 
replicate the GWT Jetty config then I think I'll be okay.

Edit for more info:

My webapp's web.xml reads as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>JettyContinuationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.ContinuationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>JettyContinuationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/bugzilla/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <!-- Servlets -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.searchsystem.gwt.server.GreetingServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>jetty-proxy-servlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ProxyServlet$Transparent</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>ProxyTo</param-name>
        <param-value>http://localhost/</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
       <param-name>Prefix</param-name>
       <param-value>/</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>greetServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dashboard/greet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>jetty-proxy-servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/bugzilla/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Dashboard.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and the link to my Bugzilla installation is in this form:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame bugFrame = new Frame("/bugzilla/");
```

Running under Jetty 6.1.26, I get this output:

```
Request Attributes
Attribute:  Value:
javax.servlet.forward.request_uri   /bugzilla/
org.mortbay.jetty.error_page    /jspsnoop/ERROR/404
javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path  /bugzilla/
testFilter  1
javax.servlet.error.message     NOT_FOUND
requestInitialized  ''
javax.servlet.forward.context_path  
javax.servlet.error.status_code     404
javax.servlet.error.servlet_name    default
org.mortbay.jetty.newSessionId  47deq3eo5kblxfrvtc5rljrg
javax.servlet.error.request_uri     /bugzi
```

lla/

Comment: It's been a while (2 months) but setting up a Jetty server in Eclipse and running the GWT project from that worked flawlessly for me. EDIT: Wow, didn't realise this was so old.

Answer (score 9):

there is no jetty.xml. GWT sets up the Server programmatically.
You can find the setup in

```
com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher
```

contained in the gwt-dev.jar

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Holgzn. Have looked at the source of JettyLauncher and related class files, but to be honest cannot work them out. I'm running Jetty 7.2.0 on Linux (Ubuntu), and GWT2.2.0. Part of my webapp enables access to a Bugzilla installation running on Apache (on the localhost). Running on GWT the link to Bugzilla works fine, but fails with a 404 not found error on Jetty. My webapp's web.xml reads as above, can you please have a look for me?

Comment: PS - the welcome page for Bugzilla is index.cgi, if that makes a difference

Comment: If you're getting 404 in one case, but it works in another, then you must be getting different URLs produced. What are the URLs (both working, and not-working) that appear in your browser address bar?

Comment: Thanks, Tim. The way GWT works is that you see in the browser address bar only the URL relating to the webapp itself (under GWT, this is http://127.0.0.1:8888/Dashboard.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997, under Jetty it's http://localhost:8080/dash/). Apache's log file indicates requests from GWT running in development mode hit Apache and responses are returned fine, but requests from my standalone Jetty  don't make it to Apache. Must be a config problem with my Jetty installation. The 404 returned is a Jetty 404 message - 'Not Found ERROR custom 404 page', i.e. this is not a 404 sent by Apache.

Comment: PS - the Jetty request log confirms that the URL requested is not found: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 -  -  [08/Mar/2011:09:30:00 +0000] "GET /bugzilla/ HTTP/1.1" 404 55

Comment: Given that GWT serves the webapp okay, I think my web.xml must be okay and it's another of the Jetty config files that's at fault?

Comment: Edit - see above for result of running under Jetty 6.1.26. I think there's a problem with no value being present for javax.servlet.forward.context_path - am I right, and if so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

See: [Serving a GWT Application with an Embedded Jetty Server](http://brandontilley.com/2010/03/27/serving-a-gwt-application-with-an-embedded-jetty-server.html) by Brandon Tilley (code extract shown below). He seems to have achieved it quite seamlessly, a process which I will be confirming myself tomorrow.

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class EmbeddedGwt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

        // Create an embedded Jetty server on port 8080
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        // Create a handler for processing our GWT app
        WebAppContext handler = new WebAppContext();
        handler.setContextPath("/");
        handler.setWar("./apps/GwtApplication.war");

        // If your app isn't packaged into a WAR, you can do this instead
        WebAppContext altHandler = new WebAppContext();
        altHandler.setResourceBase("./apps/GwtApplication");
        altHandler.setDescriptor("./apps/GwtApplication/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        altHandler.setContextPath("/");
        altHandler.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        // Add it to the server
        server.setHandler(handler);

        // Other misc. options
        server.setThreadPool(new QueuedThreadPool(20));

        // And start it up
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this post is long time ago, but could you confirm? How did you handle the dependencies?